# Change the distance of text lines in tikz nodes with Beamer

Tags: beamer, nodes, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

I have a tikz tree that doesn't fit on the slide. The theme and the linespread is given, so I only want to change the line distances of the text in the tikz nodes. But nothing worked for me :(

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\linespread{1.35}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[light]{iwona}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Dependency Tree Kernel (Culotta 2004)}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,
            n/.style={rectangle, draw, rounded corners=1mm,
            align=center, anchor=north},
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm}, 
            level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south,
            transform shape]

            \node [n] (a1){became\\Verb\\-\\-}
            child {
                node [n] (a2) {Recently\\Adverb\\-\\-}
            }   
            child {
                node[n] (a3) {Obama\\Noun\\PER\\Arg1}
            }
            child {[sibling distance=1.5cm]
                node[n] (a4) {president\\Noun\\PER\\-}
                child{[sibling distance=1.1cm]
                    node[n] 
                        (a5) {the\\Det\\-\\-}
                }
                child {
                    node[n] (a6) {of\\Prep\\-\\-}
                    child {
                        node[n] (a7) {USA\\Noun\\ORG\\Arg2}
                        child{[sibling distance=1.1cm]
                            node[n] 
                                (a8) {the\\Det\\-\\-}
                        }
                    }    
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}        
    \end{column}
    \hspace{-6ex}
    \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, 
            n/.style={rectangle, draw, rounded corners=1mm,
            align=center, anchor=north},
            level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm}, 
            level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south,
            transform shape]

            \node [n] (is){is\\Verb\\-\\-}
            child {
                node [n] (Ballmer) {Ballmer\\Noun\\PER\\Arg1}
            }   
            child {
                node[n] (still) {still\\Adverb\\-\\-}
            }
            child {[sibling distance=1cm]
                node[n] (CEO) {CEO\\Noun\\-\\-}
                child{[sibling distance=1.1cm]
                    node[n] 
                        (the) {the\\Det\\-\\-}
                }
                child {
                    node[n] (of) {of\\Prep\\-\\-}
                    child {
                        node[n] (Microsoft) {Microsoft\\Noun\\ORG\\Arg2}
                    }    
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column} 
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can try to reduce the vertical space between lines. For example, use `\\[5pt]` and change values to find an appropriately one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert
`\linespread{1}\selectfont`
above the first node definition within the `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `columns` environment contains just the trees, you may want to set the `\linespread` parameter to `1` for just the `columns` environment.

Also, the `forest` package makes drawing linguistic trees much easier.

## Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\linespread{1.35}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[light]{iwona}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Dependency Tree Kernel (Culotta 2004)}
\begin{columns}\linespread{1}
  \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={align=center,scale=.7,transform shape,draw,rectangle,rounded corners=1mm}
      [became\\Verb\\-\\-,
        [Recently\\Adverb\\-\\-,]
        [Obama\\Noun\\PER\\Arg1,]
        [president\\Noun\\PER\\-,
          [the\\Det\\-\\-]
          [of\\Prep\\-\\-
            [USA\\Noun\\ORG\\Arg2]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={align=center,scale=.7,transform shape,draw,rectangle,rounded corners=1mm}
      [is\\Verb\\-\\-
        [Ballmer\\Noun\\PER\\Arg1]
        [still\\Adverb\\-\\-]
        [CEO\\Noun\\-\\-
          [the\\Det\\-\\-]
          [of\\Prep\\-\\-
            [Microsoft\\Noun\\ORG\\Arg2]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: (+1) beaten to it! I hope that you will not mind that I've posted a modified version of your answer showing how to use styles to simplify the coding of the trees. If you object, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: @cfr: Definitely not `:)` I like your answer better than my own, actually.

Answer (score 2):

This is a modified version of [Kevin C's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220400/) showing how to use styles to reduce the code needed to typeset the trees and help ensure consistency. Whether this is useful or not probably depends on how many such trees you have to do!

`.wrap value` is used to automate the addition of linguistic categories to the nodes. So, instead of writing `Microsoft\\Noun\\ORG\\Arg2`, you can write `Microsoft, noun org arg2`. If you need to use this a lot, you probably want to abbreviate the style names a bit so that you could write say, `Microsoft, noa2` or whatever. But it is easier to understand the code with the longer names and better to choose your own abbreviations so that they make sense to you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[light]{iwona}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  noun/.style={
    content/.wrap value={##1\\Noun\\--\\--},
  },
  noun per/.style={
    content/.wrap value={##1\\Noun\\PER\\--},
  },
  noun per arg1/.style={
    content/.wrap value={##1\\Noun\\PER\\Arg1},
  },
  noun org arg2/.style={
    content/.wrap value={##1\\Noun\\ORG\\Arg2},
  },
  det/.style={
    content/.wrap value={##1\\Det\\--\\--},
  },
  prep/.style={
    content/.wrap value={##1\\Prep\\--\\--},
  },
  adverb/.style={
    content/.wrap value={##1\\Adverb\\--\\--},
  },
  verb/.style={
    content/.wrap value={##1\\Verb\\--\\--},
  },
  my tree/.style={
    for tree={align=center, scale=.7, transform  shape, draw, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm},
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Dependency Tree Kernel (Culotta 2004)}
\begin{columns}\linespread{1}
  \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
      my tree
      [became, verb
        [Recently, adverb
        ]
        [Obama, noun per arg1
        ]
        [president, noun per
          [the, det
          ]
          [of, prep
            [USA, noun org arg2
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}[T]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
      my tree
      [is, verb
        [Ballmer, noun per arg1
        ]
        [still, adverb
        ]
        [CEO, noun
          [the, det
          ]
          [of, prep
            [Microsoft, noun org arg2
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest styles]